# call_api not working with proper credentials

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using this line:
call_api($_SESSION['sessionToken'],"https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default");

to get the details of my Google Analytics but it returns nothing. when i try to open:
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default, it returns a 404 page, where can i see any changes on the Google Analytics API?
since is seems that a recent change on their part is causing this problem.

would someone be kind enough to explain this to me. or is it because of some changes on Google Analytic?

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how old is your code. It seems to be using version 2.3 of the API

The current working versions are 2.4 and 3. Version 2.3 doesn't work anymore.

Here's the documentation for the latest version of the API.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/

And here's the changelog for the management API.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/community/mgmt_changelog

Here is a guide on migrating from 2.3 to 2.4. But you are encouraged to move to 3.0, some features only work on 3.0

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdata-migration-guide

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v2/#whatsnew

Comment: how do you get the API_KEY? right now i just hard coded it in my code, what function should be used to retrieve the users data? thank you